# Solr alternates returning different versions of the same document

Tags: solr

I have the following problem with Solr 4.5.1, with a cloud install with 4 shards:

I have updated a document via the Solr console (select a core, then select "Documents"). I used the CSV format to upload the document, including the document ID.

When I query the document id from the Solr console (simple query: id:"the-id-of-the-doc-I-updated"), I alternatively obtain the old document (with the values before update, and a given *version* number), or the new document (with the values after update, and a different *version*).

No log messages in the Solr console.

Any idea what might be going on, and how to fix that problem?

Thanks in advance,

Yann

Comment: It looks like shards didn't sync docs already

Comment: Between a shard a a cache maybe? I don't have any replication going on, just one index divided in 4 shards. I send my requests always to the same server as well.

Comment: This seems to be due in a bug in Solr; the Solr console doesn't handle document routing properly. Deleting documents (via a delete query), and then adding documents from the console fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due in a bug in Solr; the Solr console doesn't handle document routing properly. Deleting documents (via a delete query), and then adding documents from the console fixed that problem.